# OpenX caching using memcached is slower than file-based caching?

Tags: memcached, ads, openx

I'm using OpenX 2.8.7 on nginx, PHP 5.3.6 (FastCGI via PHP-FPM) and APC. memcached version is 1.4.5 and have 64MB allocated to it.

I'm testing the speed of a banner delivery for a zone with 720 linked banners (all of them have several limitations - countries and 1-2 site variables).

When using file-based caching with 1200 second expiration, the banner is delivered (via php local mode tag) in 0.08-0.10 seconds. When delivered with memcached, it's always 0.13-0.16 seconds (still 1200 seconds expiry time).

The testing environment is not loaded in any way. There's a lot of free RAM.

Is it possible that OpenX with memcached will be slower than the default file-based caching?

Thanks,
Bar.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible because you have an overhead of creating a connection to your Memcache server.

I believe that the Memcache caching is more useful when you have multiple OpenX servers serving ads.

Comment: So generally using Memcache for anything will have this (huge) overhead of almost 100ms ? I don't think it's the issue here. I'll do some testing on how much time it takes to connect to memcached.